# Keep ethernet connection live during screen sleep

Tags: macos, keyboard, network, sleep-wake

I have a MacBookPro running OS X 10.8.5.

My understanding is <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Eject ⏏</kbd> puts the Mac into a sleep mode. This is fine but what I want to know if there is a way to keep the ethernet port active while in this mode?

When I come out of this mode, I notice I am signed out of my messaging, disconnected from VM's I have running, etc... The connection comes back right away but I want to prevent the connection disruption.

I was also looking at [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/46388) to "Equivalent of Win-L on Mac" which I really like as well. But again, it turns off the ethernet which I don't want to happen.

Comment: A connection requires data to be transmitted to keep it open - thus the OSX computer has to be not asleep to do the processing

Comment: I'm using two different energy saving settings myself: one for running on power supply and one for running on battery. The one running on power supply is set to put screen to rest after a time but hard drives to never go to sleep. I also have the option to put disks to sleep whenever deselected. To add the password lock you go into privacy and activate passcode requirements for sleep/screen saver.

Comment: @Mark Isn't Ctrl-Shift-Eject supposed to only put the display to sleep? The programs etc... are supposed to keep running in the background. Or maybe I misunderstood that.

Comment: I understand sleep to mean sleeping the computer and did not consider referring to just the screen. - Given that understanding this is a duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Locking my machine causes my network Connection to sleep](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41379/locking-my-machine-causes-my-network-connection-to-sleep)

Comment: The Point-to-Point protocol (PPP) is a method used when communicating data between computers via dial-up modem connections.!!? and you do not have a dial up modem do you ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Correct, I do not have a dial up modem.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd> …or… <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd> turns off the monitor without putting the computer in sleep mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do in case of long downloads.

The screen will go to sleep in time set (or when asked)- (5 minutes in my case)

Disable the Put disk to sleep when possible, and set the slider to the right.

Type this in Terminal to keep the connection active

```
ping -i 60 google.es
```

This will keep the connection alive.

the 60 is seconds, you do not need more pings then 1 per minute.

the Google.com or Google.es is irrelevant (you chose yours)

Just hit Restore Defaluts after you do not longer need those settings.

To stop terminal Ping hit ctrl-c

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you just do `ping -i 60 127.0.0.1` instead? Does the address you're pinging every minute have to actually be an external source?

Comment: it comes with Request timeout for icmp_seq 0

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this software called **No Sleep**. What is does is it keeps your computer awake even if the lid is closed. This is extremely useful if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't `caffeinate` or `pmset noidle` from the terminal do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

This happens on my iMac running OS X 10.10 So think it's a long standing bug. VLC will keep playing but Google hangouts will drop my call.